# Binding text-box to Control Vs Value in DDX

Tags: visual-c++, data-binding, mfc

When I try to bind control contents to a `CString` using code like

```
CString m_Name;
...
DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_Name, m_Name);
...
print(m_Name);
```

It doesn't seem to work - printing m_Name prints nothing. But if I use a control instead, which seems overkill, it works fine:

```
CEdit m_Name;
...
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_Name, m_Name);
...
CString val;
m_Name.GetWindowText(val);
print(val);
```

Using `DDX_Control` will solve my problems but I can't help feeling I'm misunderstanding `DDX_Text`, can someone help?

Comment: What does your Dialog code look like?  In particular, are you implementing OnInitDialog?  Have you stepped through DDX_Text?

Comment: Practically an empty dialog other than my `DoDataExchange` method, the wizard generated it. There's a trivial init call and a button handler... from your comment it seems it _should_ work the same in both of my examples? If so, I must have some subtle issue in my code rather than my understanding.

Comment: If you step through the DDX_Text call, you should be able to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that and post more details if needed.

Answer (score 4):

When you create control variable, it is initialized by the `DoDataExchange()`, called by `CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();`

From that point on you can use your `CEdit m_Name;` to get or set data as you wish.

With the "data" variable, there is no automagical synchronization: you need to call `UpdateData(FALSE);` to move data from member variables into controls, or `UpdateData(TRUE);` - from controls to member variables. This, BTW, is done by the default implementation of `OnOk()`.

Comment: Aha, it seems I simply assumed the binding was done automagically in both cases. This does make sense. Would `DoDataExchange` be a good place to call `UpdateData(TRUE)`?

Comment: Other way around: `UpdateData(TRUE)` calls `DoDataExchange()` internally. When you need to ensure that the state of UI controls is propagated to the underlying variables, call `UpdateData(TRUE)` (where `TRUE` means save-and-validate).